# Do I need to reinstall OpenVPN Connect on my guest Mac Ventura running on Parallels even though my host Mac Ventura already has it?

Tags: vpn, parallels-desktop, ventura

I have successfully installed [Mac OS Ventura](https://www.apple.com/macos/ventura/) with [Parallels](https://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) on the host machine which is an [M2 Mac Pro](https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/macbook-pro/14-inch) also running Ventura.

When I login to the guest Ventura and open Firefox, I am successfully able to access the internet / google.com.  When I turn on VPN (using [OpenVPN Connect](https://openvpn.net/client-connect-vpn-for-mac-os/)) on my host Ventura, internet connectivity is retained, however my guest Ventura loses internet connectivity.

Do I need to re-install OpenVPN Connect on my guest as well? Or can my guest somehow absorb the VPN connection from my host?

Note : when I turn VPN connection back to off on my host, the guest's internet connectivity is restored.

I am using the Trial version of Parallels (18.2.0)

When I go to Parallels Desktop >> Preferences and click on Network tab, I see :

[image]

[image]

Is this something that cannot be fixed in the Trial version?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to re-install OpenVPN Connect on my guest as well? Or can my guest somehow absorb the VPN connection from my host?

Yes, you must install VPN software for the client.

This applies to all virtualization software, and  not just Parallels (e.g. VirtualBox).  This is due to how the virtual network adapter is created/utilized to give host network (LAN and Internet) access to the virtual clients.

When you create VMs, the hypervisor software creates virtual adapters that utilize the hardware ports and services (to use Apple’s parlance) for network access.  It creates those interfaces with a specific default route where traffic for the Internet should go,  when you install VPN software, it creates a new route for your main interface, but not for the virtual one.  This is why your connectivity drops.

When you create VMs and share the network as you have done, you have to think of it as a network behind a network.  It’s no different than you “becoming” the ISP for your VM “customers.”  If one of them want to connect to a VPN, then that client must have the VPN software installed.

Comment: so just to be clear, I would have VPN running on my host Ventura and my guest Ventura running in Parallels? Or are you saying it is only necessary to run VPN on the guest Ventura?

Comment: You don’t need it on the host unless you want the host to connect to the VPN

Answer (score 0):

What network mode is the guest using? (You can find it in Devices -> Network.) Shared Networking should allow the guest to use the host's VPN connection.  [Parallels' knowledge base article](https://kb.parallels.com/en/4948) specifically mention this use case.  Note that shared networking is only available in the Pro and Business editions of Parallels.

Bridged Networking, on the other hand, gives the guest its own virtual network interface which won't go through the VPN. If OpenConnect is set to send all traffic through the VPN, it makes sense that your guest would be blocked. In that case you can install OpenConnect in the guest, but you can't run it in both at the same time.

Comment: I am currently using the Trial version of Parallels - 18.2.0 (53488).  Is this why I do not see Devices -> Network? The only thing I can see at the moment is Parallels Desktop >> Preferences and then I can select the "Network" tab from there.   Under Network, there are two options (Shared and Host-Only).

Comment: If you have clarifying questions, ask them in comments, not in your answer.